# When do you use phi coefficient in production?

Tags: javascript

I see the formula for phi coefficient reading Eloquent Javascript -http://eloquentjavascript.net/04_data.html

I get a subscript is NOT mathematical operation.

I get the breakdown of how it works here:
[Explain how the phi coefficient function works in Eloquent Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26323481/explain-how-the-phi-coefficient-function-works-in-eloquent-javascript)

But when do we actually use phi coefficient in the real world or is it something just nice to know in javascript? Can anyone provide a clear scenario?

Comment: I can't understand your notation, is that $\phi = \frac{n_{11}n_{10} - n_{10}n_{01}} {\sqrt{n_1 \cdot n_0 \cdot n_1 \cdot n_0}}$?

Comment: oops sorry, I just copied and paste the formula wrong.

Comment: The [phi coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phi_coefficient) is a standard statistical measurement. It has nothing to do with JavaScript specifically, it just is used in the book as an example algorithm that is relatively easy to implement. If you want to get some real-world example, I would suggest asking at [stats.SE]

Comment: I would also state that that seems like an overly complex example of how to work with arrays in javascript, which is what (I assume) is one of the objectives of the chapters (introducing basic data structures). I would really question if the author knows how to do a good job of explaining programming concepts after glancing through that chapter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use the phi coefficient if you were performing statistical calculations (e.g. if you were a statistician).

The example in *Eloquent JavaScript* is simply a demonstration of how you can use JavaScript to carry out that calculation. Programmers would not generally be calculating phi unless they were developing statistics applications.

Comment: Would you consider it a bit much for a beginner?

Comment: @jkcoding Not necessarily. It may require reading the section a few times to grasp all the concepts, but the foundations it is based upon are not all that complicated. I think that if you read it carefully, you will get it.

Comment: I totally suck at math. But after reading it over again and broke down the calculation I got grasp of how it works. But I agree. At first sight I was a bit overwhelmed.

Answer (score 1):

It's a very ignorant part of the book, really frustrating. They don't actually adequately cover the entire equation (especially the bottom) but if you look at how they calculate it, it'll make sense eventually. Also their code example except some JOURNAL global but they won't let you console.log or output that at all.... they force you to go to some separate page to see the data they're working on, which is a monumental mistake. You can't cover some mathematical concept for beginners, do a statistical equation, and then just have the data only accessible on some other page.