# Calculate a Phi coefficient in Java

Tags: java, confusion-matrix, statistical-test

I want to calculate a Phi coefficient in Java for a Confusion Matrix 2 x 2 
where the code so far as below :

```
double str= (trueP + falseP) *(trueP + falseN) * (trueN + falseP) * (trueN + falseN);
               double output= Math.sqrt(str);
                if (output!= 0.0)
                return (trueP * trueN) / output;
            else return 0.0;
```

where the **trueP=6930**, **trueN=6924**, **falseP=0, and falseN = 0**, the output of this code is 3629.03401901938. 
I have calculated the Phi coefficient in **excel** it returns value **1** for the same values

What is the Wrong?

Any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: Can you look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_matrix and tell us what Phi corresponds to (like Positive Predictive Value or True Positive Rate)?  That might make it easier for someone to give you help.

Comment: sova.. please look to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26323481/explain-how-the-phi-coefficient-function-works-in-eloquent-javascript i

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if every variable is double your code produces the desired output 1.0 :

just compile and run the following java class which assigns the values you want to be assigned to trueP, trueN, falseP and falseN:

```
class confusion {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    double trueP=6930;
    double trueN=6924;
    double falseP=0;
    double falseN=0;
    double str= (trueP + falseP) *(trueP + falseN) * (trueN + falseP) * (trueN + falseN);
               double output= Math.sqrt(str);
                if (output!= 0.0) {
                    double output2 =(trueP * trueN) / output;
                    System.out.println(output2);
            }
                else  {
                System.out.println(output); // Display the string.
            }
    }
}
```

the reason is that double can hold a max value big enough for your case:

```
static double   MAX_VALUE
A constant holding the largest positive finite value of type double, (2-2-52)·21023.
```

as you can see here : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @DavidWallace it answers the question because he wasn't using double previously... obviously...

Comment: Saying "here's some code that works" doesn't tell anyone what was actually wrong ... which was what the OP asked.

Comment: I also mention the assigning variables as "double" etc, and then edited about the max_value of double..

Comment: @MehdiAcademic2014 glad it works. Please accept my answer by ticking the tick box on the left if it solves your problem.

Comment: adrCoder... I'm already did that ... thanks again for your answer

Comment: below the upvote there is a tick which u need to click so that you accept my answer.. initially it is grey but when you click it it becomes green.. thanks !

Answer (score 10):

I can duplicate this error but only if `trueP`, `trueN`, `falseP`, and `falseN` are `int`s.

If they are `int`s, then this line overflows the range of `int` before it can be assigned to `double`.

```
double str= (trueP + falseP) *(trueP + falseN) * (trueN + falseP) * (trueN + falseN);
```

This value is only `1.74822976E8` when it should be `2.3023989982224E15`, which is larger than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, a little larger than 2 billion (`2E9`).

Cast the first value to a `double` to force floating-point arithmetic for the entire expression, because `double` has a much larger range of valid values.

```
double str= ( (double) trueP + falseP) *(trueP + falseN) * (trueN + falseP) * (trueN + falseN);
```

When I do that, I get your desired output of `1.0`.

To ensure valid calculations as a whole, use `double`s for all 4 variables: `trueP`, `trueN`, `falseP`, and `falseN`.